# Calling a Factory From Outside of AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, factory

How do you call a factory? As defined below.

```
angular.module('fb.services', []).factory('getQueryString', function () {
    return {
        call: function () {
            var result = {}, queryString = qs.substring(1),
                re = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g,
                m;
            while (m = re.exec(queryString))
            result[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
            return result;
        }
    }
});
alert(getQueryString.call('this=that&me=you'));
```

Comment: You would inject the factory and call the method on its instance... Its in docs. But What exactly are you trying to do? You just need an alert/or access to the service in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: I am new to Angular, and just wanting to test the service in the middle of nowhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to call your factory outside of the angular you would need to get an [injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector) from your module. i.e:

```
angular.injector(['fb.services']).get('getQueryString').call();
```

You can typically use this while writing unit test, but you should try to avoid doing this in production code.

Try not to access angular app outside, Otherwise typical usage of the factory/services etc would be through [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) while you are in the app.

Comment: To note: This requires that the service is defined above this call. This will not delay for the instantiation of the services and can thus throw undefined service provider errors.

Answer (score 0):

you can dependency the module and use it.

```
angular.module('fb.controller', ['fb.services'])
  .controller('fb.controller',['getQueryString',function(getQueryString){
     alert(getQueryString.call('this=that&me=you'));
 }])
```

Comment: This only works in Angular, the question is for code running outside of Angular context.

Comment: the question is asking how to from "outside" angular